# QtMediaplayer wont work on frameless and translucent background PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I am making a videoplayer with QMediaplayer but it wont work on frameless and translucent background window.I want to make a round corner windows so i need frameless and translucent window.
Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QFrame
import sys     
class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget Example") 
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.frame=QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background:grey;border-radius:20px;')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        #self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget(self.frame)
        videoWidget.setGeometry(10,10,580,380)
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                         QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("C:/Users/mishra/Desktop/HiddenfilesWindow/10000000_1874628825927192_6229658593205944320_n(1).mp4")))
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
    def handleError(self):
        print("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())
          
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Player()
    
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After setting translucent background it only plays audio not video.Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem on PyQt5 5.9.2

Comment: Did u uncomment means remove those comment lines i have mentioned.But anyway  I face that problem in 5.15 @alec

Comment: Yes I uncommented those lines

Comment: What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QRegion
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
     

class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget Example") 
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.frame= QFrame(self)  
        
#        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background:grey; border-radius: 20px;')
        self.setStyleSheet("Player {background: #000;}")                   # +++
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
#        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
#        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)                                   # +++
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()                                       # +++
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)                                      # +++

        
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
#        videoWidget = QVideoWidget(self.frame)             
#        videoWidget.setGeometry(10,10,580,380)
#        self.resize(600,400)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
            QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("Samonastrojka.avi")))
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(self.rect()), 20, 20)
        reg = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.setMask(reg)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    def handleError(self):
        print("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())
   
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Player()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This question *is* interesting. I can't check your answer, but I know I can trust your testing. Nonetheless, your answer still doesn't provide enough context (again). Does it solve the problem? Yes. Does it provide **actual** and didactical help (which is one of the most important principles of SO, since context/argumentation should always be provided)? Absolutely **NOT**. Don't get me wrong: I appreciate your efforts (I can recognize your "arrowed-answers" screenshots, and I like them), but still, I have to say, your answers are **not** good answers as long as you just write your "Try it.".

Comment: Yes it works fine.that means there is problem in Translucent background or is it a Bug?Can u make the corner smooth like my previous one?its edges are not so smooth.Thanks for your effort man. @S. Nick