# Why is QVideoWidget not showing up in my application?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm building a video converter application based on FFmpeg, and one of the additional features is the ability to trim the video visually. For this purpose I've created a new QWidget that gets called by pressing a button in the main window where you use QVideoWidget and some buttons and labels to trim your video. Upon clicking the confirm button, the widget closes and returns a string containing the trim syntax for FFmpeg.

I'm creating the GUI using QtDesigner and implementing it via the uic module.

Python 3.9 with PyQt5 5.15.6

**THE PROBLEM**

The video widget `video_widget` doesn't show up in my application. Upon clicking the play button you can hear the audio, but the frame where `video_widget` was supposed to appear remains empty. Everything else works as expected.

I first wrote the code in a separate test file, (with a different, simpler .ui file) where it works perfectly fine. I only copied the working code and adjusted it to communicate with the main window.

I'm 99% sure the problem is related to the UI file. I tried swapping the UI file for the old/simple one in the merged code from the main app, and it works as expected. I read some posts about how aligned widgets cause some problem, so I unaligned everything related to the QVideoWidget but it didn't help.

**THE CODE**

*trim.py*:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as qtmm
from PyQt5 import QtMultimediaWidgets as qtmmw
from PyQt5 import uic


class Trim(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Trim, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('trim_mwe.ui', self)

        # GENREAL BUTTON SETUP
        self.discard_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        # DEFAULT VALUES
        self.file = ''

        # VIDEO WIDGET SETUP
        # self.video_widget = qtmmw.QVideoWidget()

        # MEDIA PLAYER SETUP
        self.media_player = qtmm.QMediaPlayer(None, qtmm.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        # EVENTS ASSIGN
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(self.duration_change)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.position_change)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_move)

        # BUTTONS ASSIGN
        self.play_btn.clicked.connect(self.play)

        # LAYOUT SET
        # video_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        # video_layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        # video_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        # self.video_frame.setLayout(video_layout)

    def play(self):
        # handles play/pause
        if self.media_player.state() == qtmm.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.media_player.pause()
        else:
            self.media_player.play()

    def time_convert(self, pos):
        # converts milliseconds into a readable format
        minutes, seconds = divmod(pos / 1000, 60)
        timecode = f'{minutes:0>2.0f}:{seconds:.2f}'

        return timecode

    def duration_change(self, dur):
        # updated the slider range based on video duration
        self.slider.setRange(0, dur)

    def position_change(self, pos):
        # change the slider position to reflect video position
        self.slider.setValue(pos)
        self.current_time.setText(self.time_convert(self.media_player.position()))

    def slider_move(self):
        # change video position on slider move
        self.media_player.setPosition(self.slider.value())

    def load_video(self, new_file):
        # gets info from main window
        self.file = new_file

        # loads the video into frame
        self.media_player.setMedia(
            qtmm.QMediaContent(qtc.QUrl.fromLocalFile(new_file)))


# the main app
app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)

# trying to replicate how passing the data works in the main app
file = r"C:\Users\Viktor\[PYTHON]\converter\tests\1.mp4"
videoplayer = Trim()
videoplayer.load_video(file)
videoplayer.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*trim_mwe.ui:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>979</width>
    <height>793</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <family>Segoe UI</family>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QWidget {
    color: white;
    font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;;
}</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="base_frame">
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QFrame#base_frame {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="title_bar">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">QFrame {
    background-color: #f77f00;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}</string>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="title">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">QLabel {
    color: white;
    font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;;
    font-weight: bold;

}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>TRIM</string>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="spacer_title_bar">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>677</width>
             <height>18</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="main_frame">
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="main_layout">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QFrame" name="video_frame">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">QFrame {
    background-color: none;
    border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    border-radius: 0px;
}</string>
           </property>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="topMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="rightMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="bottomMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QVideoWidget" name="video_widget" native="true">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>5</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="play_btn">
             <property name="enabled">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>30</width>
               <height>30</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Segoe UI</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
               <weight>75</weight>
               <bold>true</bold>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(33, 213, 93);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(27, 172, 75);
}

QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}
</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="icon">
              <iconset resource="resources/resources.qrc">
               <normaloff>:/icons/icons/play_arrow_white_24dp.svg</normaloff>:/icons/icons/play_arrow_white_24dp.svg</iconset>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="checked">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="set_ss_btn">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>30</width>
               <height>30</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #444444;
}

QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}
</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="icon">
              <iconset resource="resources/resources.qrc">
               <normaloff>:/icons/icons/align_horizontal_left_white_24dp.svg</normaloff>:/icons/icons/align_horizontal_left_white_24dp.svg</iconset>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="set_to_btn">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>30</width>
               <height>30</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #444444;
}

QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}
</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="icon">
              <iconset resource="resources/resources.qrc">
               <normaloff>:/icons/icons/align_horizontal_right_white_24dp.svg</normaloff>:/icons/icons/align_horizontal_right_white_24dp.svg</iconset>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QSlider" name="slider">
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    background: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: white;
    /* border: 1px solid #777; */
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

/*QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: #f77f00;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item alignment="Qt::AlignVCenter">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="current_time">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>60</width>
               <height>0</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QLabel {
    color: #7f7f7f;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>00:00.000</string>
             </property>
             <property name="textFormat">
              <enum>Qt::PlainText</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="alignment">
              <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="discard_btn">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>70</width>
               <height>22</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>70</width>
               <height>16777215</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    padding: 0px;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f77f00;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #222222;
    color: white;
}

QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #262626;
    border-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);

}

</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>DISCARD</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QVideoWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources>
  <include location="resources/resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Can you provide the `ui` file?

Comment: Oh no, I completely forgot to upload it, sorry, I updated the original question with a link to my gdrive

Comment: You don't have to upload it using external resources, as question should be self-contained, you have to [edit] your question and include it.

Comment: can i just copy the entire content and paste it in as a code? (like with the py file) because it's pretty long.

Comment: Then create a copy and remove all unnecessary widgets until you get to a minimal layout.

Comment: ok then, i updated the question with the ui file + updated the python code to reflect the changes

Comment: With your *current* code, I can correctly play videos. Note that with your *previous* code it wouldn't have worked because you were trying to set *again* a layout. If, anyway, you're still not able to play, try running the program from the command prompt and see if there is any debug.

Comment: Yes, I managed to correctly play video when running the trim window separately, but when I copy the code over to the main application (with the only difference being that the video path is passed from the main window) it suddenly stops working. The issue seems to only happen with QVideoWidget, as it won't show up even after I give it a background color. If I change to type to QWidget I can see a red box.

I tried running the code using the 'Run File in Python console' in PyCharm but nothing useful came up.

Comment: The fact is that right now your code works as expected, meaning that since we cannot reproduce your problem, we cannot help you understanding it. Please take your time and provide a [mre].

Comment: I understand, also, could you please explain what did you mean by 'trying to set again a layout' ?

Comment: If you look at the Object Inspector in Designer, you'll see that `video_frame` has a horizontal layout set (which contains `video_widget`). In your original code you created a *new* `video_widget` and added it to a *new* `video_layout`, but then you did `self.video_frame.setLayout(video_layout)`. As said, `video_frame` already has a layout, and Qt doesn't allow to do `setLayout()` on widgets that are already managed by another layout (run the original script in the prompt and you'll see a warning about that), with the result that any widget added to that new layout will *never* be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped the working and non-working UI and python files so many times, that I got forgot which combination is supposed to work, but I came to a conclusion that the reason why QVideoWidget wasn't showing was caused by the following flag in `__init__`:

`self.setAttribute(qtc.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`

Apparently when you set this attribute QVideoPlayer breaks. You can read more about it [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/121146/qtmediaplayer-wont-work-on-frameless-and-translucent-background-pyqt5) and [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/41686/solved-how-to-play-a-video-on-a-translucent-qwidget).

There is a workaround if you want to still retain the translucency, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994186/13213412), but it doesn't work with my current shadow method + it looks jagged compared to the WA_TranslucentBackground method, so I just dropped the rounded edges and shadow on this particular widget.